# Ogg vs amr which format to use Android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I need to develop the ***Voice Recorder*** using `MediaRecorder` Api for my application. There are different format while setting `mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);`, I am little confused that which format to use for better quality and size? Should I think in a way that `ogg` file size is lesser than other or vice versa. Please advise accordingly that which format should be used. *Please advise keeping in mind that Recorded file will then be sent to server*

Answer (score 1):

you need read this [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

For my personal opinion you should use AAC ELD (enhanced low delay AAC) format. This format have good quality and good record size.